# XSLT presentation in the XML node order

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML of the below structure.

```
<catalog>
  <cd><name/></cd>
  <cd-r><name/></cd-r>
  <cd-r><name/></cd-r>
  <cd><name/></cd>
  <cd><name/></cd>
</catalog>
```

I separate the presentations of the `cd` & `cd-r` elements. I need to have the presentation displayed in the order of the XML nodes. The position of the `cd` & `cd-r` elements will be random.

Output should be some thing like

```
<p> This is a CD </p>
<p> This is a CD-R </p>
<p> This is a CD-R </p>
<p> This is a CD </p>
<p> This is a CD </p>
```

Comment: Right, and how's that going?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the normal processing will ensure that order so write two templates

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>This is a CD</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd-r">
  <p>This is a CD-R</p>
</xsl:template>
```

in your stylesheet and you are done.